# Passport JS Custom callback called 3 times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm building an express js api with passport js, and in order to be able to return custom error messsages formatted as json I'm using [custom callbacks](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/).

When I provide an unknown email the custom callback I wrote is called 3 times, resulting in `Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`. Which makes sense.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my implementation:

## Strategy:

```
const localLoginStrategy = new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: "emailAddress"
}, (emailAddress, password, done) => {
    // Called once
    User.findOne({
        where: { emailAddress }
    }).then((existingUser) => {
        // Called once
        if (!existingUser) { return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid email/password combination", status: 401 }); }

        return existingUser.comparePassword(password);
    }).then((userData) => {
        return done(null, userData);
    }).catch((err) => {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid email/password combination", status: 401 });
    });
});

passport.use(localLoginStrategy);
```

## Express middleware for authentication using custom callback:

```
const requireUsernamePassword = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.body.emailAddress || !req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "No emailAddress and/or password provided" });
    }
    // Called once
    passport.authenticate("local", { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
        // Called three times!
        console.log("authenticate callback")
        if (!user || err) {
            return res
                .status(info.status || 400)
                .json({ message: info.message || "Authentication error" });
        }
        req.user = user;
        return next();
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

Comment: what is calling your requireUsernamePassword middleware? Can the multiple calls come from earlier in the call stack? Could you try to add a ˋreturn User.findOne(....)` I doubt it's coming from that but it can hurt and is generally (not always) good practice to return promises. Did you log the value of err/user/info for each of the 3 calls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `done` function multiple times.

I believe when you call `return done(...)` in the `then` method, the next `then` will call `done` again.

So that's why your `callback` function from `requireUsernamePassword` has been called more then one time.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm always struggling with promisses, altough I figured it out by the time you answered, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

To check your mandatory request body fields create one generic middleware that will check required field and return appropriate return code. Just like below.

```
module.exports = function checkParams(params) {
  params = params || [];
  return function(req, res, next) {
    var valid = true;
    if(Array.isArray(params)) {
      params.forEach(function(_param) {
        valid = valid && !!req.body[_param];
      });
    }
    if (valid) { next() } else {return res.status(400).end();} //this is for missing required parameters
  };
};
```

Now lets say for example you have two APIs. Login and CreateUser. API routes should looks like below

```
app.post('/Login', checkParams(['emailAddress', 'password']), passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), actualLoginMethod);


app.post('/CreateUser', checkParams(['userName', 'Phone']), passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), actualCreateUserMethod);
```

If either of these parameter (userName and Phone in /CreateUser + emailAddress and password in /Login) is missing then it will return 400 status and stop execution from that point, you may change the checkParams's logic as per your need.

If required parameters are available then it will check JWT local strategy. Once request is through to both the check points then it will call actual method.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: I like your idea, but it wan't the problem I was having. I will implement the check params function though.